# jQuery No-Ui-Slider set pointer to desired value

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm using the NoUIslider from Refreshless.com (http://refreshless.com/nouislider/)

```
$("#slider").noUiSlider("init", 
       { dontActivate: "lower", startMax: "40%", scale: [0, 500],
       tracker: function(){
                                foo();
                            }, 
       clickmove: function(){
                                foo();
                            }
                        });
foo();
```

Value of the slider is read as:

```
   Math.ceil($("#slider").noUiSlider("getValue", {point: ""}));
```

I need to set the slider to a value that the user enters in a text box. The docs are minimal, and I tried a couple of things, but nothing moved the slider:

```
$("#slider").noUiSlider("move", {
        moveStyle: "animate",
        setTo: [members],
        scale: [10, 500],
        saveScale: true
});
```

All options have exhausted, and I need your help. Thanks

Comment: What is the value of members that you're setting the "setTo" attribute to?

Comment: its an integer between 10 and 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by disabling the animation and setting the value to an integer in the same range - you do not need to work out an equivalent for the scale as I had thought earlier.

Answer (score 1):

For the setTo parameter, use an array that specifies the values of both sliders. Even when I used this plugin with a single slider, the setTo was ineffective unless I used an array with two values. Change your code to something like this:

```
$("#slider").noUiSlider("move", {
    moveStyle: "animate",
    setTo: [30, 200],
    scale: [10, 500],
    saveScale: true
});
```

If you are using a single slider, just set both array members to the position you want the single slider to be (i.e. [30, 30]).

As an aside, I discontinued using this slider plugin as it was too quirky. I started using Egor Khmelev's slider plugin (http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/) and it works great.

Comment: thanks. but that is not required, I got it working by disabling the animating.